# Chrome Browser - Keyboard shortcut to correct spelling of word?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, spell-check

I hate right clicking misspelt words in text boxes within browsers to correct spelling.

Wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut to replace the misspelt word with the best match when the cursor is in/before/after the word?

Alternatively is there a browser plugin or could I set up keybindings to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To correct the underlined word with the keyboard, with the cursor on the underlined word press:

> <kbd>context menu</kbd> <kbd>down</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>

Repeat <kbd>down</kbd> as needed.

[image: Context Menu]

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question because I think what I was looking for is to auto-replace the best/closest correction. (Basically looking to avoid the step "Repeat [down] as needed".) But in any event since this question is attracting confusing answers I'm labelling this the "most correct".

Comment: [This answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/118830/125115) to [my question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/118827/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-have-google-correct-one-misspelled-word/118830#118830) on Web Apps seems to be slightly more clear as to why this works.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>down arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I just tested this in Chrome.  Sadly, when text is highlighted, it appears that the text isn't spell checked.  A "context menu" is properly brought up, and it even includes an option to search for the [text which is highlighted], but no spell check option is provided.  If you right-click, a spell check option is provided.  I would call this a violation of the standard for modern Microsoft Windows, which is for <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd> to do the same thing as if you right-clicked on [where the keyboard cursor is]/[whatever is selected].

However, if you make a typo, and press the <kbd>space bar</kbd> (so the "word" is spell checked and the red underline appears), and then get your keyboard cursor back into that word, without using <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>arrow</kbd> to highlight text, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd> will spell check the word.  <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> will select the top proposed correction, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> will choose it.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is three year old thread but responding anyway.  This works:

1) Search button + Shift + Volume Up button

2) Highlight correct word with arrow keys then press Enter

Pressing Search causes the top row of keys to act as function keys.  The Volume Up button is the tenth one over so F10.  Search + Shift + F10 = Shift F10 which is the standard shortcut for showing the context menu.

EDIT: this answer works on a Chromebook only

Comment: This is only particular to your laptop or keyboards particular layout. Search/Volume/Media keys are not standard and don't have the same locations on every device. A lot of laptops make them the default over F1-F12 keys unless you press the Function key, but really all you are pressing is Shift+F10.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  My answer is for a Chromebook, not the Chrome browser in general.

Answer (score 0):

As far as chrome is consider there are no keyboard shortcut for spell check. Alternatively,There's an extension in the Chrome store called Ginger that does spell checking. When a word is spelled wrong it will be highlighted in blue. All you do is hover over the word and the word it thinks you meant will appear above it, just click the word and continue on.

Comment: (Note sure just how this helps... the question was asking for keyboard shortcuts, which may be useful for eliminating the requirement to even use a mouse.  This method requires adding an extension, and then instead of being able to quickly right-click, needing to hover (a.k.a. wait) for a pop-up.  That sounds like it would increase the minimum time needed for the hand to be away from the keyboard and on a mouse, directly accomplishing the exact opposite of the desirable goal that I mentioned.)

Comment: And the shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a Chinese keyboard and then you can use shortcuts in Chrome:

[image: 1]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).